# Referencing Cross project compilation within custom DiagnosticAnalyzer - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis, microsoft-code-analysis

Can anyone let me know about any way we can access cross project compilation (in same solution) inside custom DiagnosticAnalyzer.

I need to analyze value of an argument for a particular method invocations. This argument could be a field from source file of another project as well. In this case DeclaringSyntaxReferences results empty. This works fine if the field is from source file of same project.

I have seen some workarounds for building workspace and solution explicitly within analyzer code but that approach doesn't look appropriate.
Could you please suggest is there any way of achieving this?